# See if subarray of array exists

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var array = [[10, 8, 2], [5, 7, 1], [3, 9, 4]];
```

I need something that tells me if the sub object exists, without throwing an error. Here's an example:

```
elementExsits(array[0][4]);
//false

elementExsists(array[1][2]);
//true
```

The function `elementExsists` would verify it the path exists. I've tried:

```
if (typeof array[3][2] !== 'undefined') {};
```

But it just says

```
Cannot read property '2' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You check one property at a time. Stop if you encounter undefined:

```
if (typeof array[3] !== "undefined" && typeof array[3][2] !== "undefined") {
}
```

Or better:

```
if (3 in array && 2 in array[3]) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very compact way of doing it and works well.

Answer (score 2):

A simple if statement can decide if an element exists:

```js
var array = [[10, 8, 2], [5, 7, 1], [3, 9, 4]];

if (array[1] && array[1][2]) {
  console.log('exists');
} else {
  console.log('doesn\'t exist');
}

if (array[10] && array[10][2]) {
  console.log('exists');
} else {
  console.log('doesn\'t exist');
}
```

Trying to access an array value that doesn't exist returns `undefined`, so if statements will switch based on the result.

Comment: Try the same idea on `array[10][1]`.

Comment: "works" only if the array doesn't contain falsy values like 0 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 2):

[Salman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52433698/2206733) works for your scenario.
Or, you can also create a dynamic function to return the value at the index, or undefined if not found.

```js
var array = [[10, 8, 2], [5, 7, 1], [3, 9, 4]];

function elementExists(array, ...indices){
    return indices.reduce((el, i) => el && el[i], array)
}

console.log(elementExists(array, 0, 4))
console.log(elementExists(array, 1, 2))
console.log(elementExists(array, 3, 2))
```

Comment: @SalmanA Yes. For example .. `array = [[10, [1,[11,12]],8, 2]]` and `elementExists(array,0,1,1,0)` gives you `11`. (Four levels deep).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and check if the index exists. Then proceed with the next nested array.

This solution works with the array and an array of indices and uses a short circuit with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), if the index is not in the given array.

```js
function elementExsists(array, indices) {
    return indices.every(i => Array.isArray(array) && i in array && (array = array[i], true))
}

var array = [[10, 8, 2], [5, 7, 1], [3, 9, 4]];

console.log(elementExsists(array, [0, 4]));  // false
console.log(elementExsists(array, [1, 2])); //  true
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an array, and a list of indexes, and using [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) iterate the indexes. If all indexes are not `undefined` the element exists. If event one is `undefined`, the element doesn't exist.

```js
const elementExists = (array, ...indexes) => {
  let current = array;
  
  return indexes.every(index => {
    current = array[index];
    
    return current !== undefined;
  });
};

const array = [[10, 8, 2], [5, 7, 1], [3, 9, 4]];

console.log(elementExists(array, 0, 4)); // false

console.log(elementExists(array, 1, 2)); // true

console.log(elementExists(array, 3, 2)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function elementExists(a, i, j) {
  return Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(a[i]) && a[i].length > j;
}

console.log(elementExists(null, 0, 1));
console.log(elementExists(undefined, 0, 1));
console.log(elementExists(0, 0, 1));
console.log(elementExists('foo', 0, 1));
console.log(elementExists([], 0, 1));
console.log(elementExists([null], 0, 1));
console.log(elementExists([0], 0, 1));
console.log(elementExists([[]], 0, 1));
console.log(elementExists([[],[]], 0, 1));
console.log(elementExists([[3],[9]], 0, 1));
console.log(elementExists([[3,2],[9]], 0, 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this answer. Looks like it's extremely universal.